Creating an SSH connection with double NAT
I am trying to figure out how to create an SSH connection in my current setup which is:

my public IP is that of the mobile ISP I use - and it's shared across many users
my ISP then assigns me a private IP in the range 10.95.75.0

which means that the trick of logging my IP address with
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

does not work.
On top of that, my mobile router (TP-Link M7000 V3) does not provide NAT (v2 does, but without a visible IP address, what's the point?).
I do have a machine with a fixed IP address - just not on this netweok.
I kind of remember reading you can do something "inside out" (for lack of a better description).
Is that true or only my fantasy? and if yes, what is it?

You can connect to outside server, a gateway, and setup reverse port forwarding: ssh gateway.example.com -R 22222:localhost:22. Let's call the machine where you do this client.
Now, on gateway you'll see that sshd process is listening on the port 22222, and when you run ssh -p 22222 localhost there, it will connect to the client. It'll listen on localhost; you may use ssh -g -R 0.0.0.0:port:localhost:22 ..., but for the gateway to obey -g you need to enable GatewayPorts in its configuration (default is no); refer to man sshd_config for details. If you do this, you may now connect to gateway:port from anywhere and it will get you directly to the client.
You can make this into a service on this client system, with all the stuff: authentication via key, the key is restricted heavily on the gateway, startup from systemd, restart on disconnection, and so on. For instance, the following is the usable systemd service description similar to the one I use for similar purpose:
[Unit]
Description=SSH reverse tunnel
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=ssh user@gateway.example.com -i /path/to/private/key -g -R 22222:localhost:22 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

(I believe I also have timeouts/keepalives configured somewhere, for it to kill the connection if network was disconnected.)
The public key may be restricted on the gateway as follows:
restrict,port-forwarding,command="/bin/false" ssh-...


There is a public gateway service that does exactly this: SSH-J. I am not affiliated with the service. The author and owner of the service, ValdikSS, sometimes can be found on the ServerFault too, but not very often, unfortunately.
